# How to capture the value of data attribute?

Tags: javascript

The javascript snippet that we have is :

```
<a href="#" class="n-contact" data-test-socialmedia="{'type': 'facebook', 'options':{'country': 'US' }}">Link</a>
```

I would like to retrieve the value of data-test-socialmedia type. Based on that I would like to add the conditional statement to check if the data-test-socialmedia type is facebook. As we have many data attributes like this in the site.

I tried several ways and I get object as the value. But i need the actual value in this case it is facebook. Kindly help.

Comment: _"I tried several ways"_ I don't see any of them...

Comment: Should this question have a jquery tag? It sounds like a jquery question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery

```js
var elementData = $(".n-contact").attr("data-test-socialmedia").replace(/'/g,'"'),
  parsed = JSON.parse(elementData);

console.log(parsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="n-contact" data-test-socialmedia="{'type': 'facebook', 'options':{'country': 'US' }}">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
//first get element
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('n-contact')[0];
//get data and replace single quotes with double quotes to create valid JSON
var d = el.dataset.testSocialmedia.replace(/'/g, '"')
//parse JSON to javascript object
 var parsed = JSON.parse(d, null)
 //get country if type is facebook
 if(parsed.options == 'facebook')
    console.log(parsed.options.country)
```

```html
<a href="#" class="n-contact" data-test-socialmedia="{'type': 'facebook', 'options':{'country': 'US' }}">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = document.querySelector('.n-contact').getAttribute('data-test-socialmedia').replace(/'/g,'"');    
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var result = obj.type;
console.log(result);
```

it would work.